# How to add two more kafka brokers in the local machine if my current running kafka broker already has the data

Tags: apache-kafka

I have one broker running in my local machine with Windows OS which has 2-3 topics with messages stored. I want to scale up my machine by adding two more broker instances. I have followed all the steps to configure 3 brokers on the **same** machine by creating different properties file.

My `broker=0` getting shutdown when I am starting `broker=1` server with below error.

> [2019-07-11 13:56:33,580] INFO Stopping serving logs in dir C:\kafka_2.12-2.2.1\data\kafka (kafka.log.LogManager)
>   [2019-07-11 13:56:33,585] ERROR Shutdown broker because all log dirs in C:\kafka_2.12-2.2.1\data\kafka have failed (kafka.log.LogManager)

Is it possible to add more brokers if my existing broker instance has the data. 
Or do I need to delete the data directory and freshly start the broker 0. Is there any possibility to preserve the data without deleting it from the kafka server.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can add brokers to your cluster and migrate/spread data across all your brokers.

The [Expanding your cluster](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion) section in the documentation details the steps to achieve this.

After starting the new brokers, you basically need to use the `bin/kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` tool (other 3rd party tools also exists) to move data onto them.

Please note however that adding brokers on the same machine does not provide a lot of resiliency as if the machine was to go down, all brokers would be affected. But if you want to just play around and learn about Kafka that may be fine.

Comment: Do you have an example of 3rd party tools you mentioned?

Answer (score 1):

To run multiple brokers on the same physical machine, it is necessary for each broker in the config to specify a unique **broker.id**, different **log.dirs** and ports in **listeners**.

For example,

```
config/server{1,2,3}.properties
```

in every config set difference

```
broker.id=<id>
log.dirs=/data/kafka<id>
listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:909<id>
```

When all three brokers start, new topics will be created evenly throughout the cluster, but old ones need to be rebalanced.

Comment: I have implemented the above steps which you have specified. The problem which I faced was After starting the 1st broker(which has topic with messaged) when I start another broker in different terminal, the first broker getting stopped without effecting the 2nd broker.

Comment: I edited the log.dir to new directory and able to start different brokers in the same machine. One thing I found is, the meta data get copied to broker=0. Means I can see the topics with older settings but no messaged inside the broker=0.

Comment: > One thing I found is, the meta data get copied to broker=0. Means I can see the topics with older settings but no messaged inside the broker=0.

I apologize, but I didn’t quite understand what it meant, you couldn’t tell in more detail, but it’s better to attach full configs and how you started